# Do gamma rays not follow the Beer-Lambert law?

Tags: electromagnetism, gamma-rays

I was looking at an info table for radionuclides, and it said that for F-18, the 511keV gamma rays have a 1st half-value layer of 7mm, and a 2nd half-value layer of around 4mm (Edit: in lead).  Why is there a first and second HVL?  I thought electromagnetic waves follow the Beer Lambert law (I ~ exp(-x/L)), and so no matter how far youve penetrated, the next HVL should be the same.

What am I missing?

Edit: I found out a broad spectrum beam gets attenuated more at the beginning, because a beam gets hardened (lower energies die out).  But that means the second HVL is larger than the first, not the other way around.  Plus, the 511 emission from the electron/positron annihilation is a narrow beam.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you are missing that quantum mechanics is needed for gamma rays,

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't even know where to begin to understand quantum's effect on gamma.  My 3rd year quantum course stopped at the hydrogen atom.